# MySQLdb module installation problem for python

Tags: python, django, yum

I installed MySQLdb module in centos VPS using yum and it says successfully installed producing no error.  but when I browse the python site it displays the error. "Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb". Details of the error can be seen at http://74.53.127.172/. I also  tried to install this module from the zipped file but it produces following error:

```
_mysql.c: In function â_mysql_ConnectionObject_get_proto_infoâ:
_mysql.c:1633: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âope        nâ
_mysql.c:1634: warning: implicit declaration of function âmysql_get_prot        o_infoâ
_mysql.c:1634: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âcon        nectionâ
_mysql.c: In function â_mysql_ConnectionObject_get_server_infoâ:
_mysql.c:1648: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âope        nâ
_mysql.c:1649: warning: implicit declaration of function âmysql_get_serv        er_infoâ
_mysql.c:1649: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âcon        nectionâ
_mysql.c:1649: warning: passing argument 1 of âPyString_FromStringâ make        s pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c: In function â_mysql_ConnectionObject_infoâ:
_mysql.c:1665: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âope        nâ
_mysql.c:1666: warning: implicit declaration of function âmysql_infoâ
_mysql.c:1666: error: â_mysql_ConnectionObjectâ has no member named âcon        nectionâ
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the following command to install other packages required to run mysql in centos smoothly

```
>> yum install python-devel
>> yum install MySQL-devel
>> yum install zlib-devel
>> yum install openssl-devel
```

Happy coading :)

Answer (score 0):

Try spawning a python interactive shell then import MySQLdb and see if you get the same error, in which case the module was not successfully installed. 
Try "locate mysqldb" and give us the output .